# Missing file or resources for cross compilation

Tags: c, ubuntu, compilation, header, openwrt

I am trying to cross compile a C code which uses a header file mcrypt.h. I am compiling my code in Ubuntu distribution and my target is an openwrt distribution. I am getting the below error while cross compiling,

```
  fatal error: mcrypt.h: No such file or directory
  #include <mcrypt.h>
                     ^
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You need to find out where that file comes from, because it's not a system header. Then you should examine if you need that package, and if you do then install it for your target so it's available for your cross-compiler.

Comment: Thank you for your comment , I think for `mcrypt.m` `libmcrypt-dev` package must be installed, but I don't know how to do it for my target distribution

Comment: In openwrt's `make menuconfig` select libmcrypt package. Read this doc for details: https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/build